# Attempting to load list of values in column for Angular Table

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm struggling with trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong, mostly down to not having a good understanding of AngularJS due to being new. The main goal is that I'm trying to list out all the values in the additionalText list out on the front-end, but it seems to be causing issue with this error:

> Error: [$http:badreq] Http request configuration url must be a string or a $sce trusted object.  Received: []

Context:
I have table in my application that relies on the API, this variable contains a list and outputs the following:

```
{
  "name": "TEST",
  "description": "TEST",
  "additionalText": [
    {
      "name": "TEST",
      "description": "TEST",
      "lockId": 0
    }
    {
      "name": "TEST",
      "description": "TEST",
      "lockId": 0
    }
  ],
  "lockId": 0
}
```

The API is working as expected, I can carry out all the necessary REST calls successfully. So I'm not struggling with that, the front-end is where I am having some difficulty.

HTML:

```
<td data-title="'additionalTexts'" sortable="'additionalTexts'">
    <span ng-repeat="additionalText in additionalTextList[entity.name]">
        <i>{{additionalText.name}}</i><br>
    </span>
</td>
```

AngularJS:

```
 $scope.refreshTextTable= function() {
    SpringDataRestService.query(
        {
            collection: "APIURL"
        },
        function (response) {
            var additionalTextRoles = response;
            $scope.textTableOptions = new NgTableParams({}, {
                dataset: additionalTextRoles,
                counts: [],
            });
            // Also populate a list of all linked roles
            for (var i = 0; i < additionalTextRoles.length; i++) {
                var additionalTextRole = additionalTextRoles[i];

                // This approach allows you to inject data into the callback
                $http.get(additionalTextRole.additionalText).then((function (additionalTextRole) {
                    return function(response) {
                        $scope.additionalTextList[additionalTextRole.name] = response.additionalText;

                    };
                })(additionalTextRole));
            }
        },
        function (response) {
            // TODO: Error Handling
        }
    );
};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm really struggling with this one.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this below code:

```js
$scope.refreshTextTable = function() {
  SpringDataRestService.query({
      collection: "APIURL"
    },
    function(response) {
      var additionalTextRoles = response;
      $scope.textTableOptions = new NgTableParams({}, {
        dataset: additionalTextRoles,
        counts: [],
      });
      // Also populate a list of all linked roles
      for (var i = 0; i < additionalTextRoles.length; i++) {
        var additionalTextRole = additionalTextRoles[i];

        // This approach allows you to inject data into the callback
        $http.get(additionalTextRole.additionalText).then((function(additionalTextRole) {
          return function(response) {
            $scope.additionalTextList = response.additionalText;

          };
        })(additionalTextRole));
      }
    },
    function(response) {
      // TODO: Error Handling
    }
  );
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>

<td data-title="'additionalTexts'" sortable="'additionalTexts'">
  <span ng-repeat="additionalText in additionalTextList">
      <i>{{additionalText.name}}</i><br>
  </span>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message says the url must be a string.

For debugging purposes, `console.log` the URL:

```
for (var i = 0; i < additionalTextRoles.length; i++) {
    var additionalTextRole = additionalTextRoles[i];

    // This approach allows you to inject data into the callback
    var url = additionalTextRole.additionalText;
    console.log(i, url);
    $http.get(url).then((function (additionalTextRole) {
        return function(response) {
            $scope.additionalTextList[additionalTextRole.name] = response.additionalText;

        };
    })(additionalTextRole));
}
```

Also note that the `response` object returned by the $http service does not have a property named `additionalText`. So it is likely that the intention is `response.data.additionalText`. To avoid the [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression), use the `forEach` method:

```
additionalTextRoles.forEach( role => {
    var url = role.additionalText;
    console.log(url);
    $http.get(url).then((function(response) {
        $scope.additionalTextList[role.name] = response.data.additionalText;
    });
});
```